# Why can't I solve this merge conflict on Magit?

Tags: magit, git

I am working on a feature via Pull Request. While I was working, `main` branch evolved.

Now, I want to put my changes on the Pull Request **on top** of latest `main` branch. This means I want to rebase.

Hence, I proceed with:

1 - Pressing `F` to `Pull`

2 - Pressing `-r` to `Rebase local commits`

3 - Pressing `e` as `elsewhere` and choosing `origin/main`

Ok. Now a merge conflict happens. See:

[image]

It seems, that I have to make a choice:

[image]

I am picking the red one!

Now, I am committing. After pressing `r` again I choose `continue`. But, unfortunately, I **can't** continue!

The mini-buffer echoes the following message:

```
Could not apply 1fa2cedf... income_balance_reports.cljs - fix order Tax and Reclass on ATB
```

If my understanding is correct, even though merge conflicts usually go around "pick your version", in this case, apparently, there is only one choice, otherwise, I am going to "change the order" of events and history won't make sense.

Is my understanding correct?
Is there an alternative for this beyond "just pick the green" version?

Comment: In the first picture I read `could not apply 641a549e`, the message in the minibuffer is `could not apply 1fa2cedf`. Shouldn't you just make another choice, and continue again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, although the interface shows two possibilities, the only way to successfully continue on this rebase was to pick the lower (green) option.

Otherwise, apparently, the history would be screwed-up.

The hint was given by [@dalanicolai](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/26163/dalanicolai)